# How to select multiple values in a listbox inside of a gridview editItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

If I have a dropdownlist I know I can..

```
SelectedValue='<%#Bind("AgencyID")%>'
```

I want to do the same with a listbox but select multiple values.  I was trying to use gridview.FindControl("listbox")  but it always is null.  Can someone guide me in the right direction?  Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I am not sure whether I should edit someone else's question or not. But i have the same problem and need a good solution as soon as possible. I have already taken 2 days searching for a good solution for the same.

[Please see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568703/binding-listbox-checkedlistboxs-selectedvalue-using-objectdatasource-when-multis)

I have gone through some of the following links but didn't get much help and still trying to get the solution.

Links I have gone through
http://www.gutgames.com/post/Using-a-ListBox-Using-SelectionMode-Multiple-with-a-GridView.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1003876.aspx/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved...  I just set the selected values when the listbox is being databound.

Comment: @Mike...Please suggest how you binded your listbox...I have run into the same problem...can you place some code here..

Comment: @Mike: You should always provide some detail when answering your own question (or any question for that matter), so that your solution can help others who encounter this problem in the future.

Comment: For future reference, I have used the solution from the second link of Mike's first post with success. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568703/binding-listbox-checkedlistboxs-selectedvalue-using-objectdatasource-when-multis